# How to find the name of longest stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database which contains 100's of stored procedures. I want to find which the longest stored procedure in these. How can i find it?

Currently i am using

`Select text,MAX(len(text)) 
from syscomments
group by text;`

But i am not able to find the name of stored procedure in it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sys.comments` divides long definitions into 4000 character chunks. Use `sys.sql_modules` to avoid this issue.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS Name, 
    LEN(definition) AS Length, 
    CAST((SELECT definition AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')) AS XML) AS Definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsProcedure')=1
ORDER BY LEN(definition) DESC
```

Comment: +1, might want to add a `, LEN(definition)` to the select list just for the fun of it!

Comment: For Bonus fun I've added a column that will retrieve the whole definition. (The XML trick avoids it being truncated in management studio)